# Puedo hacer mi comando batch en todas partes?

Tags: windows, batch, línea-de-comandos

Tengo mi comando batch y queria saber si hay una forma de instalarlo o moverlo alguna parte para poder usarlo no solo en la carpeta donde lo cree sino en otras partes, se pudede mover alguna carpeta especifica en windos o tengo que aplicarle un comando especial para instalarlo o moverlo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si puedes apuntando la carpeta al path en las varaibles de entorno de windows

Vas a tu pc, click derecho en propiedades, click en opciones avanzadas del sistema y te saldra de ultimo variables de entorno. Le das click y te saldran todas tu tienes que copiar la ruta de donde esta tu archivo bat ej: C:/users/Tu_usuario/desktop/carpeta/ y crear una nueva variable de entorno con esa ruta